# Approval status after copying sharepoint issue

Tags: list, item, status, approval

In SharePoint I have got 2 lists : list01 and list02

On my list01 I have a workflow.

In the list01, if the approval status of my item is "approved" then I copy the item in list02.

My problem is :

the copied item in my list02 (yet "approved" in list01) have a approval status "waiting for approval"

Strange ?

How to keep it "approved" ? What I do not do well ? I have to change my workflow on list01 ? Create a workflow on

list02 ? Settings/configure on my list02 ?

I don't understand this behavior.

Comment: sorry my "hello" was cut, HELLO !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In list 2, you would go into List Settings, and click on Versioning Settings. Set the require content approval to No.

Comment: Hello, it was the good way.